# How to open a WPF project with Blend in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, blend

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Professional Edition and have a WPF project.

I'd like to open my WPF project with Blend but the option doesn't exist in my visual studio.

Should I install Blend separately? How can I make the option visible and enable it?

Look at this video: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/showcase/details.aspx?uuid=ab9788fc-cd18-474a-942c-61754e9e428b

there is an "Open for Blend" option when right clicking on the project.

Comment: Expression blend is no more standalone app. its now part of Visual studio 2012.

Comment: I have VS 2013 and there is no option that says Open In Blend. To me, it does not look like it is part of Visual Studio. I have Blend but I have to open it separately, how does one integrate it in VS 2013?

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate a new instance of blend 2012 and open the corresponding project in that.. This is very basic.. is it not working?

Comment: What he's asking is for a quick route.  In Blend you can right click an open the project in VS... but there's no option to do it the other way around.  The video shows it, but that option doesn't exist for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same exact problem with using VS2013 Ultimate SP2.

It would appear that this only actually works when it's a Silverlight project, but once you open up Blend for Visual Studio you're able to go to `File -> Open Project/Solution...` and select the project you want to design with Blend.

As far as I am aware this is the only way to open Blend without looking through the VS 2012/2013 program folders.  I have tried it several times with WPF (even right-clicking on specific XAML files) with no success.

This may have been fixed, so I will be updating VS2013 to the latest version (SP3) and update this answer with my findings.